# Get Certificate and Signature values in Java

Tags: java, certificate, digital-signature

I have a requirement where I need to invoke a webservice. For invoking that webservice I need to provide certificate chain and signature value (datatype in webservice is String) in the SOAP request, from Java.

I have generated the source code from the wsdl using wsimport and using that in my Java program. I have a digital signature certificate file (certificateFile.pfx) (with password available to me) .

The final SOAP message sample should be like

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:v = "http://www.something.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v:Auth>
            <v:userID>xxxxxxxxxx</v:userID>
            <v:password>xxxxxxxxxx</v:password>
            <v:certChain>xxxxxxxxxx</v:certChain>
            <v:signature>xxxxxxxxxx</v:signature>
        </v:Auth>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

After generating the java source code from WSDL, for Auth, I am setting value like this.
(all the below 4 fields are string datatype)

```
Auth authInfo = new Auth();
authInfo.setUserID(userId);
authInfo.setPassword(password);
authInfo.setCertChain("");
authInfo.setSignature("");
```

Here I am not getting what to set for CertChain and Signature.

Since I have a certificate file, I tried this

```
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
// Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File(certificateName)),
                            certificatePassword.toCharArray());
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =
    (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(
        certificateAlias,
        new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(
            certificatePassword.toCharArray()));
X509Certificate cert =
    (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
```

and used

```
authInfo.setSignature(new String(cert.getSignature()));
```

But none worked. `cert.getSignature()` returns binary data not really a string.

I am not getting what to set for those two fields. How to do make use of my certificate file to get the `certificateChain` value and signature value in Java ?  Unfortunately I can not contact webservice providers to get more information on this.  I think If I get the `certificateChain` and signature in byte array, I can do `new String(byte[])` and use that value in the SOAP fields. How to get `byte[]` value of `certificateChiain` and signature ?

How do I resolve this ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you need to encode your signature to [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. Base64 is the most widely used way to deal with binary data, such as signatures, that should be transferred via text-based protocols such as WDSL. There is a plenty of good libraries to encode to and decode from Base64, such as [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) or [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html).

Comment: Alexander, the Base64 class exists in so many libraries (packages), like you mentioned apache commons, Guava and also in com.ibm.xml.crypto.util (IBM JDK), com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils and so on. How do I make sure which library to use ? When I run with multiple libraries ,the encoded data I see is different for each. I know it depends on the way library is implemented to encode the data. But which is the universal encoding approach ? 

Also how to Do I get the Base64 encoded data of certificate chain from certificate. ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use cert.getEncoded -> this will return certificate values, not signature. You want to see your signature so you need to use

```
byte[] signature = cert.getSignature();
 System.out.println(Base64.encode(encoded));
```